# Complete my palindrome

Tags: code-golf, palindrome

Create a function (preferably) or a program that takes an ordered collection and outputs the *smallest possible* palindrome that starts with the input.

For example:

```
>>> completePalindrome( [1, 2, 3] )
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

>>> completePalindrome( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2] )
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

>>> completePalindrome( "race" )
"racecar"
```

You may choose to support as many of your language's data types as you want to.

Have fun!

Comment: Are we allowed to support just one datatype, eg a string or a list?

Comment: [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,1] isnt a palindrome.